# Which USB keyboards will work with an iPad 3?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, usb

It is [possible](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BAT5bpJv450) to connect a USB keyboard to an iPad (3rd generation) using the camera connection kit.

However, my [Apple keyboard](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MB110Z/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad?fnode=56) does not work so which ones do?

Yes I know I could buy a wireless keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but it doesn't seem to work under the new iOS6.

See: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqCk6nz80Ps